# Getting an array of frequencies from Hilbert Transform, which one is the correct?

Tags: python, transform

Suppose B is a signal of duration T sampled each dt = 1sec.
After employing empirical mode decomposition (EMD) to B,
n number of intrinsic mode functions (IMF) would be extracted.
Using Hilbert transform, instantaneous frequencies (IF) and instantaneous amplitudes (A) were calculated. As a result, the IF is a matrix with the number of rows equal to the length of signal B and the number of columns equal to n (so is A).

```
import emd
B  = np.sin(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100000))+0.05*np.random.rand(100000)
dt = 1
time_vect = np.linspace(0, len(B), len(B))

## Get IMF's
imf = emd.sift.sift(B)
## Get instantaneous phase, frequency, and instantaneous amplitude
IP, IF, A = emd.spectra.frequency_transform(imf, sample_rate, 'hilbert')
```

Now I want to construct a marginal Hilbert spectrum using IF and A. I found the following formula in the literature:

[image] where,

[image]

```
T = len(B)
h = np.zeros(len(A.T))
for i in range(len(A.T)):
    h[i] =(1/T)*np.sum(A.T[i]**2)
```

What confuses me is that the result of integration is a vector of length n (that is the number of IMFs). On the other hand, the values of IF for each IMF differ from others and they are not increasingly sorted (like what we have in wavelet transform). My question is, what is supposed to be the frequency for each IMF. For example, if I wanted to plot h[i] as a function of frequency how should I do it?

Comment: Is your index frequency or something else seems like IF is the frequency. Then you have to loop through elements of IF to run function on each frequency.

Comment: @bgorkhe Thanks for taking the time to reply! I am not sure I understand your answer completely though. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: This link is useful for your calculations. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html

Comment: @bgorkhe I am not sure that this helps a lot to be honest. Could you please elaborate a bit on your previous answer?

Comment: Its been a while I have used these techniques but were you able to follow this tutorial. That might be the right path to follow.  https://emd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/emd_tutorials/02_spectrum_analysis/emd_tutorial_02_spectrum_01_hilberthuang.html#making-hilbert-huang-transform-plots

Comment: Based on the equation that you wrote you need to sum of A^2(v,t) over the Time samples for each frequency component. Select one frequency integrate the A^2 of that frequency over the 0-T range. That is my understanding.

Comment: @bgorkhe Thanks so much for taking the time to reply! This is one way of doing it, however the second way( the one I have tried to calculate in this question ) enables you to replace the index A^2 to A^q and generalize for higher order. I want to generalize to higher orders, that;s why I have tried to use the second way. Do you have any idea how I could generalize to higher order using the way you suggested?

Comment: in numpy you can use np.power(A, q) if that's what you are looking for.